# using kubectl delete command to remove core-dns pod blocked / No activity

Tags: kubernetes

I found my coredns pod throw error: `Readiness probe failed: Get http://172.30.224.7:8080/health: net/http: request canceled (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)` . I am delete pod using this command:

```
kubectl delete pod coredns-89764d78c-mbcbz -n kube-system
```

but the command keep waiting and nothing response,how to know the progress of deleting? this is output:

```
[root@ops001 ~]# kubectl delete pod coredns-89764d78c-mbcbz -n kube-system
pod "coredns-89764d78c-mbcbz" deleted
```

and the terminal hangs or blocked,when I use browser UI with using kubernetes dashboard the pod exits.how to force delete it? or fix it the right way?

[image]

Comment: coredns is one of the core service. It shouldnt be deleted. why do you want to delete it?

Comment: I just delete the pod , not the service.@PEkambaram because the coredns could not start.

Comment: I just delete the pod , not the service.@PEkambaram because the coredns could not start.

Comment: i meant coredns pod

Comment: if coredns is not started. you need to check logs and find out why it is not getting started

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are deleting a `pod` which is monitored by `deployment` controller. That's why when you delete one of the `pods`, the controller create another to make sure the number of `pods` equal to the replica count. If you really want to delete the `coredns`[**not recommended**], delete the `deployment` instead of the `pods`.

```
$ kubectl delete deployment coredns -n kube-system
```

Comment: absolutely not. by deleting the deployments.apps, you cannot even upgrade or recreate the coredns pods and down to another round of kubeadm reset/init

Answer (score 0):

Answering another part of your question:

> but the command keep waiting and nothing response,how to know the
>   progress of deleting? this is output:
>
> ```
> [root@ops001 ~]# kubectl delete pod coredns-89764d78c-mbcbz -n kube-system
> pod "coredns-89764d78c-mbcbz" deleted
> ```
>
> and the terminal blocked...

When you're deleting a `Pod` and you want to see what's going on under the hood, you can additionally provide `-v` flag and specify the desired verbosity level e.g.:

```
kubectl delete pod coredns-89764d78c-mbcbz -n kube-system -v 8
```

If there is some issue with the deletion of specific `Pod`, it should tell you the details.

I totally agree with @P Ekambaram's comment:

> if coredns is not started. you need to check logs and find out why it
>   is not getting started – P Ekambaram

You can always delete the whole `coredns` `Deployment` and re-deploy it again but generally you shouldn't do that. Looking at `Pod` logs:

```
kubectl logs coredns-89764d78c-mbcbz -n kube-system
```

should also tell you some details explaining why it doesn't work properly. I would say that deleting the whole `coredns` `Deployment` is a **last resort** command.